# For loops and semicolons on java, the code is running just once

Tags: java, for-loop

Why this code print "hello" once?

I know that if I remove the `;` it will run 10 times.  My question is: why it is running just once when the semicolon is there?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) ;
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Comment: The `System.out.println` you mean? Because the semicolon makes it not be part of the loop anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have your syntax wrong. It is supposed to be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

However, this only prints "Hello" nine times, so you will have to modify the loop a bit:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

By putting `;` at the end of the following line, you are limiting the scope within this line only

Answer (score 0):

By putting `;` at the end of the following line, you are limiting the scope within this line only

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) ;
```

i.e. the following lines are not in the scope of the loop:

```
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, the braces after a for loop (or if statement, while loop, etc.) are optional. A single statement, ending in a semicolon, can be specified.

i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.println("hi"); //Prints hi 5 times.`

Your semi colon means that the for loop body is blank - It does nothing 10 times.

The braces after your for loop create a new block, which is valid code in Java. Doing so creates a new scope. Since this scope is not in a conditional statement, it is executed, meaning your message is printed once.